# Need help in typing reusable component for `next-intl

Tags: typescript, internationalization, typescript-generics, react-typescript, next-intl

I'll do my best to explain what I need.
If you're not already familiar with `next-intl`, It's a package that provides internationalization for Next.js apps.

### The Problem:

[The developer of next-intl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/343045/amann) working on a beta version of next-intl that supports the app router of next.js. I installed this beta version `next-intl@3.0.0-beta.16`. Up to this point, everything is ok.

The problem is that next-intl doesn't work in async components. and devs have to move the calling of the `useTranslations` hook to another sync component.

I use async components for everything almost. Instead of moving the all texts into other components. I've built a reusable component `<T />` (stands for Text or Translation). and want to pass the translation `key` as a prop. like `<T k="home.hero.title" />` (`k` because `key` is already reserved).

### My implementation:

Assuming the translation file is like this:

```json
{
  "hello-world": "Hello World",
  "home": {
    "title": "Acme",
    "hero": {
      "description": "whatever"
    }
  },
  "login": {
    "button": "Login"
  }
}
```

`components/translation.tsx`

```js
import { useTranslations } from "next-intl";

export function T({ k }: {
  k: TYPEME_LATER;
}) {
  const translate = useTranslations();
  return translate(k);
}
```

To keep you on the scene, my all question is about the `TYPEME_LATER`.

#### 1. First, I wrote it like this:

```js
import { useTranslations } from "next-intl";

type TranslationKey = Parameters<ReturnType<typeof useTranslations>>[0];

export function T({ k }: {
  k: TranslationKey;
}) {}
```

But this way, Typescript suggests only nested keys like `title`, `hero.description`, `button`, and `hello-world` (take a quick look at the previous JSON snippet). but, by this way the next-intl won't find these keys, because it misses the scope `home`, `login`.

#### 2. So, I tried another solution:

```js
import { useTranslations } from "next-intl";

type useTranslationsParam = Parameters<typeof useTranslations>[0];
type TranslationKey = Parameters<ReturnType<typeof useTranslations>>[0];

export function T({
  scope,
  k,
}: {
  scope: useTranslationsParam;
  k: TranslationKey;
}) {
  const translate = useTranslations(scope);
  return translate(k);
}
```

like the magic, that worked as expected. Now I can do this anywhere:

```js
export default async function Page() {
  return <>
    <T scope="home" k="title" />
  </>
}
```

It renders as expected. but if you go back to the `TranslationKey` type declaration, You can see that it accepts any key regardless of the scope. This might lead to a bug when writing a key that doesn't exist in the scope.

My question is I want to make the `k` suggest only the keys within the scope. or if there is another approach let me know.

Thanks in advance for your interest. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't know how next-intl works but if you have access to the schema object you could use [this here](https://tsplay.dev/WJ1G5m).

Comment: Thanks, starting to make sense. 
by (schema) do you mean a messages file like typeof `en.json`?

Comment: Yes, something that is well typed

Comment: Note that using a component for translations doesn't allow you to pass translated labels as attributes, which expect strings (e.g. `aria-label={t('label')}`). That might be another point to consider before wrapping the `t` function, just as a heads-up!

Comment: Thanks @amann I just wanted a quick way to put text in async components without the need to move it to another component.  I've implemented it based on the Filly type. It works fine now. I'll put my implementation in an answer with the hope of seeing better built-in implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update

`next-intl@3.1` came with support async components using `await getTranslations(namespace?)`

```js
export async function Page() {
  const t = await getTranslations("home");
  
  return <div>{t("title")}</div>
}
```

---

---

### Original Answer

For anyone trying to build the same concept, this is my end implementation:

```
import { useTranslations } from "next-intl";

interface Props {
  /** Message key */
  path: Paths<IntlMessages>;
}

export function Text({ path: key }: Props) {
  const translate = useTranslations();

  return translate(key);
}

type Paths<Schema, Path extends string = ""> = Schema extends string
  ? Path
  : Schema extends object
  ? {
      [K in keyof Schema & string]: Paths<
        Schema[K],
        `${Path}${Path extends "" ? "" : "."}${K}`
      >;
    }[keyof Schema & string]
  : never;
```